# Why is this coffeescript not compiling "correctly"?

Tags: javascript, coffeescript

I have the following in a Rails app:

```
# projects.js.coffee
jQuery ->
  $('#project_title').typing ->
    start: (event, element) ->
      element.css 'background', '#fa0'

    stop: (event, element) ->
      element.css 'background', '#f00'
      alert 'send request to populate samples'

    delay: 400
```

However, in the compiled js file I'm getting the following:

```
(function() {

  jQuery(function() {
    return $('#sprinkler_word').typing(function() {
      ({
        start: function(event, element) {
          return element.css('background', '#fa0');
        },
        stop: function(event, element) {
          return element.css('background', '#f00');
        }
      });
      alert('send request to populate sprinkle samples');
      return {
        delay: 400
      };
    });
  });

}).call(this);
```

Why is the "alert" call not being included in the "stop" function? I assume my syntax is incorrect, but I can't see where. Thanks.

Comment: Mixed tabs and spaces?  It [looks](http://coffeescript.org/#try:%0AjQuery%20-%3E%0A%20%20%24('%23project_title').typing%20-%3E%0A%20%20%20%20start%3A%20(event%2C%20element)%20-%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20element.css%20'background'%2C%20'%23fa0'%0A%0A%20%20%20%20stop%3A%20(event%2C%20element)%20-%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20element.css%20'background'%2C%20'%23f00'%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20alert%20'send%20request%20to%20populate%20samples'%0A%0A%20%20%20%20delay%3A%20400) fine.

Comment: I never noticed you could create deeplinks to the code there. Nice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pasting your code into the "Try Coffeescript" widget the code you expect, i.e. the alert inside the stop function:

```
jQuery(function() {
  return $('#project_title').typing(function() {
    return {
      start: function(event, element) {
        return element.css('background', '#fa0');
      },
      stop: function(event, element) {
        element.css('background', '#f00');
        return alert('send request to populate samples');
      },
      delay: 400
    };
  });
});
```

Therefore I'm guessing tabs and spaces messing up indentation.